# How to fill QTableWidget from json in Python

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm working on statistical software which takes data from Cloud Firestore database, puts it into *QTableWidget* and then into chart. I'm able to create offline backup of database (json below). How can I achieve to fill *QTableWidget* with data from it?

In my table, I've got 4 visible columns - Date, Type, Published, Sent and one hidden - ID (formatted date, e.g. 050719)

This is .json file I get from database

```
"{\"events\": {\"050719\": {\"Type\": \"Conference\", \"Published\": \"4\", \"Sent\": \"3\", \"Date\": \"05.07.2019\"}, \"050919\": {\"Type\": \"Conference\", \"Published\": \"23\", \"Sent\": \"35\", \"Date\": \"05.09.2019\"}, \"120719\": {\"Type\": \"Conference\", \"Published\": \"3\", \"Sent\": \"4\", \"Date\": \"12.07.2019\"}, \"150719\": {\"Type\": \"Conference\", \"Published\": \"4\", \"Date\": \"15.07.2019\", \"Sent\": \"2\"}}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general method, but the basic idea is to iterate through the components as shown below:

```py
import json
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    data = "{\"events\": {\"050719\": {\"Type\": \"Conference\", \"Published\": \"4\", \"Sent\": \"3\", \"Date\": \"05.07.2019\"}, \"050919\": {\"Type\": \"Conference\", \"Published\": \"23\", \"Sent\": \"35\", \"Date\": \"05.09.2019\"}, \"120719\": {\"Type\": \"Conference\", \"Published\": \"3\", \"Sent\": \"4\", \"Date\": \"12.07.2019\"}, \"150719\": {\"Type\": \"Conference\", \"Published\": \"4\", \"Date\": \"15.07.2019\", \"Sent\": \"2\"}}}"
    # or
    # with open('/path/of/json') as f:
    #     data = json.load(f)
    d = json.loads(data)
    keys = ["Date", "Type", "Published", "Sent"]
    labels = keys + ["ID"]

    w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, len(labels))
    w.setColumnHidden(4, True)
    w.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)

    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(d["events"].items()):
        rows = [value[k] for k in keys] + [key]
        w.insertRow(w.rowCount())
        for j, v in enumerate(rows):
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(v)
            w.setItem(i, j, it)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

```py
import json
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class DateTimeDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(DateTimeDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        value = index.data()
        option.text = QtCore.QDateTime.fromMSecsSinceEpoch(value).toString("dd.MM.yyyy")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    data = # ...
    d = json.loads(data)
    keys = ["Date", "Type", "Published", "Sent"]
    labels = keys + ["ID"]

    w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, len(labels))
    delegate = DateTimeDelegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)
    w.setColumnHidden(4, True)
    w.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)

    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(d["events"].items()):
        rows = [
            value[k]
            if k != "Date"
            else QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(value[k], "dd.MM.yyyy").toMSecsSinceEpoch()
            for k in keys
        ] + [key]
        w.insertRow(w.rowCount())
        for j, v in enumerate(rows):
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            it.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, v)
            w.setItem(i, j, it)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: About the _data_ variable - how could I make it load from .json file in same location as .py code?

Comment: @M.Obrcian change `data = ....` to `with open('/path/of/json') as f:`
    `data = json.load(f)`

Comment: Okay, now I'm getting the ID written into the first column (where should be the date - I've got Date-Type-Published-Sent and ID is hidden). How can I rearrange it?

Comment: Thanks, by the way, this is same software as in my previous question, so how could I make it work with that DateTime Chart? I guess, I would somehow had to convert date to *MSecsSinceEpoch* and than add it to table through delegate, but I'm clueless.

Comment: @M.Obrcian I have already updated my answer, do you want something else?